# Show a resource for his owner and avoiding deeply nested routes at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails guide advice to avoid deeply nested routes, so I am wondering how to make this relationships work without nesting routes more than one level :

A User has many courses

A Course has many lessons

A lesson has many questions

A Question has many answers

**The constraint : a user can only see his own courses, lessons, questions, and answers (the app needed to be that way)**

As a first try we can do this (which break the recommendation cited above) :

```
resources :users
resources :courses do
  resources :lessons do
    resources :questions do
      resources :answers
    end
  end
end
```

This unfortunately results in long nested routes, but I found out that we can pass `shallow: true` like this

```
resources :courses, shallow: true do
  resources :lessons do
    resources :questions do
      resources :answers
    end
  end
end
```

In short, the shallow option will not generate nested url for these action (:show, :edit, :update, :destroy), for example the show action for lessons will be `lessons/2` instead of `courses/1/lessons/2` but the inconvenient of this is : I am not able to scope this by the current_user.

To make sure the lesson shows only for his/her owner I should do something like :

```
def show
  current_user.courses.find(params[:id].lessons.find(params[:lesson_id])
end
```

Which means the course id should be passed as parameter in the url, which doesn't apply for shallowed routes. (The same thing for the other routes: i.e : to show a question we should pass course_id, lesson_id and question_id as params)

Any idea how this can be solved ?

**UPDATE :**

to make my question simpler :

If we are going to follow Rails recommendation and don't nest resources more than one level, then how we can get an **answer** that belongs to the `current_user` without passing `course_id` and `lesson_id` and `question_id` in the url ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What  you are getting caught up on is a common misstake where you confuse context with authorization. The role of nesting in REST is not too decide who gets what - nesting tells you about the associations between resources.

For example:

```
/users/:user_id/comments
```

Creates a meaningful restful URI that tells us what to expect if we request that endpoint - comments by that user.

When scoping by the current user you want to get the user from the session or a token and not by the params:

```
class ReviewsController
  # POST /books/:book_id/reviews
  def create
    @comment = Book.find(params[:books_id]).comments.new(comment_params) do |c|
      c.user = current_user # from the session
    end
    # ...
  end
  # ...
end
```

Using a param to specify the current user is really bad as it makes it childs play to spoof. A malicous user can perform actions as other users just by altering a param or using firebug to alter the hidden input on the form.

---

Your scenario is peculiar but if I have understood you correctly the core of the problem is actually providing the indirect associations - not the routing.

```
class User
  has_many :courses
  has_many :lessons, through: :courses
  has_many :questions, through: :courses
  has_many :answers, through: :courses
end

class Course
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :questions, through: :lessons
  has_many :answers, through: :lessons
end

class Lesson
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, through: :questions
  has_one :user, through: :course
end

class Question
  belongs_to :lesson
  has_many :answers
  has_one :course, through: :lesson
  has_one :user, through: :course
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
  has_one :user, through: :question
  has_one :lesson, through: :question
  has_one :course, through: :question
end
```

---

```
# routes.rb
resources :courses, shallow: true do 
  resources :lessons
end

resources :lessons, only: [], shallow: true do
  resources :questions
end

resources :questions, only: [], shallow: true do
  resources :answers
end
```

---

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController

  # We only need question for the nested routes
  before_action :set_question, only: [:new, :create, :index]
  before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # /lessons/:lesson_id/answers
  def index
    @lessons = @course.lessons
  end

  # /lessons/:id
  def show
    @lesson = current_user.questions.find(:id)
  end

  private

  def set_question
    @course = current_user.questions.includes(:answers)
                          .find(:question_id)
  end

  def set_answer
    @answer = current_user.answers.find(:id)
  end 
end
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, however I didn't said that we should pass user_id as a param in the url, if we take a lesson for example, we have a user has_many courses, a courses has_many lessons, how would you show a lesson with a specific id as param and be sure that this lesson belongs to the current_user ? you need obligatory to do `current_user.courses.find(:course_id).lessons.find(:lesson_id)`

Comment: No - you only ever really need one level of nesting. http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

Comment: can you please show me in an example how you can get a question that belongs to current user ? without passing course_id and lesson_id in the url ?

Comment: also, from the url you sent me read this : `a specific member can always be accessed directly by an id, and shouldn’t need scoping (unless the id is not unique, for some reason)`

Comment: Are the questions write in or multiple choice?

Comment: what do you mean? a user can write many questions himself (don't ask me why) and in the show page he should see his own questions, a user can't see other users' questions

Comment: all resources you see above should only be accessed by their owner :)

Comment: I edited it with an example. Its pretty late so I appologise for an any errors. You should at least get the basic gist of how to set it up.

Comment: Thats also the most peculiar and useless Q&A app ever... :)